# RSQLite insert ignore to skip duplicates

Tags: sql, r, sqlite

I have a sqlite table with columns x, y, and z.  x and y are unique keys and z is the value.

I would like to use R to insert data into this table.  If a duplicate record - based on the x and y fields - is being inserted, I would like sqlite to reject the record and continue.  In sql, this can be done using "insert or ignore", can this be done using the R package RSQLite?  So far there is an option dbWriteTable which writes an R data frame to a sqlite table, but it doesn't seem like there is an option for "insert or ignore"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the source where dbWriteTable constructs the sql string and sends it to sqlite.  You can use this modified source to allow the "insert or ignore" syntax

https://gist.github.com/jeffwong/5925000

Answer (score 2):

Rework of answer from @Karsten W to load all data with same process:

```
library(RSQLite)

# create table
con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbExecute(con, "CREATE TABLE tab1 (a CHAR(6) NOT NULL, b CHAR(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (a, b));")

load_data <- function(x) {
    # load data
    # we want to add only the new combinations of a and b
    insertnew <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tab1 VALUES (:a,:b)")
    dbBind(insertnew, params=x)  # execute
    dbClearResult(insertnew)     # release the prepared statement
}


# new data
dat1 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=LETTERS[11:20], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
load_data(dat1)
print(dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1;"))

# new data, partly redundant
dat1 <- data.frame(a=letters[2:11], b=LETTERS[12:21], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
load_data(dat1)
print(dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1;"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
results <- dbSendQuery(exampledb, "insert or ignore ...")
```

dbSendQuery takes raw SQL, per the [DBI spec](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/DBI.pdf). Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

Since I had a similar problem, here is a one-shot solution:

```
library(RSQLite)

# create table
con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
dbExecute(con, "CREATE TABLE tab1 (a CHAR(6) NOT NULL, b CHAR(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (a, b));")
dat1 <- data.frame(a=letters[1:10], b=LETTERS[11:20], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dbWriteTable(con, "tab1", dat1, append=TRUE)

# new data, partly redundant
dat2 <- data.frame(a=letters[2:11], b=LETTERS[12:21], stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# we want to add only the new combinations of a and b
insertnew <- dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO tab1 VALUES (:a,:b)")
dbBind(insertnew, params=dat2) # execute
dbClearResult(insertnew)  # release the prepared statement

# should be TRUE
as.numeric(dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tab1;"))==11
```